# Reading CSV file into a 3D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, csv, vector

I'm doing a project for which I need to read into an array, a few 180x360 grids of numbers. So I'm trying to put them into a 3D array `vector<vector<vector<float> > > array;` which is like 180x360x(~5).

So far the data I've been working with is separated by spaces so I've been using a code like this to do that:

```
    char infileName[] = ".../nasadata/180x360_CLD_FR.dat";
    ifstream inFile(infileName);

    if (!inFile.is_open()){
        cerr<<"Opening failed"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }


    while (!inFile.eof()){
        for(int k=0; k<=360; k++){
            for(int j=0; j<=180; j++){
                inFile >> array[j][k][3];
                cout << array[j][k][3]; // so I can see what it's putting into the array
            }
        }
    }

    inFile.close();
```

This worked fine before, but now the variables are separated by commas (and line breaks after each line of 360) it fails to read them in at all. I've been trying to look at using the `getline` function but none of the questions other people have asked are similar enough for me to be able to figure it out as they are all using strings rather than 3D arrays.

Another approach I've been trying looks like this:

```
    string line;
    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;

    while( getline( inFile, line ) )
    {
        istringstream iss( line );
        string result;
        while( std::getline( iss, result, ',' ) )
        {
            array[row][col][3] = atoi( result.c_str() );
            cout << array[row][col][3] << " ";
            col++;
        }
        row++;
        col = 0;
    }
```

This seems to successfully read in the file, but fails to put the correct values into the array. It gets the first and last lines correct, but enters just zeros for every other line.

Edit: I need to apologize for being a noob/idiot. The second of these two codes actually works, however the function `atoi` (which I was unfamiliar with) parses the string and returns an **integer**. Changing that the `atof` makes it return suitably precise numbers.

Hopefully my thought process here can be of help to anyone with a similar question!

Comment: It's not really different if you use a 3D array.
The strategy you need to addopt is, getline and store it in an array, then procces the array, if you hit a comma, store the data in your 3D array, set the new start index for the next value and continue until you reach the end of the string (the getline one)

Comment: But with the getline function the format is `getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim) `. If you try to make it goes straight to an array instead of a string it doesn't work does it? I have tried this.